# validating optional fields with play framework

Tags: scala, validation, playframework-2.0

I've been searching for past half an hour but didn't found any solution or a page that actually describes **validation of optional fields using play framework**.
Here's my form:

```
var myForm = Form(mapping(
    "id" -> optional(longNumber),
    "field" -> text
      .verifying("field is required", value=> value.length > 0),
    "heading" -> optional(text)
      .verifying("heading should be less than 50 characters", value=> value.length < 51) // Need something like this validation
  )(FormDetails.apply)(FormDetails.unapply))
```

When its `optional(text)` field then `.verifying` asks for `Option[...]`.

The validation I want to perform is: *If heading is present than check its length (max 50 characters)* & *If there is no heading then do nothing*

I want to do the validation with field declared in `mapping()` not after declaring all field then validating together. If you can provide some links, that will also work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is write an if... else... that will fit your needs (be it an `optional(text)` or `text`) while performing validation in `verifying` method.

```
var myForm = Form(mapping(
    "id" -> optional(longNumber),
    "field" -> text
      .verifying("field is required", value=> value.length > 0),
    "heading" -> optional(text)
      .verifying("heading should be less than 50 characters", value=> if (value.isDefined) value.get.length <= 50 else true)
  )(FormDetails.apply)(FormDetails.unapply))
```

Comment: `value => value.forall(_ <= 50)` would be more elegant